# How to convert single line text box into multiline textbox in nintex workflows sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, nintex-workflow

In Nintex workflow, I have a Single line text box which supports only 255 characters, now I want to convert that single line text box into Multiline text box, can we do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Showing a Text variable as Multi Line Textbox in a Task Form, please see if the solution in this article works for you.
https://community.nintex.com/nintex-for-office-365-15/showing-a-text-variable-as-multi-line-textbox-in-a-task-form-18532

1.So first you should open the "Assign task" or "Start task process" action (depending which you use).

2.To activate it you have to add Nintex app to the site you store your workflow. Go to site settings, then "New", and choose "Nintex Form for Office 365"

3.After it is added open your workflow again.
Before editing a form be aware, that your variable is set as "Multiple lines". Click on the "Variables" button on the Workflow Designer's ribbon.

4.then click the variable you want to be a multiline. Be sure you have the checkbox "Initiation" checked. Then click the small gear icon next to the checkbox.

5.On the opened form with variable settings, check the field "Multiple lines":